# How to convert csv to txt with column alignment? better don't have to use other libraries

Tags: python, csv, formatting, text-files

I want to convert csv to txt file without losing column alignment and better don't use any libraries.

I saw silimiar quesition. But I had a hard time install prettytable in pycharm even I download the module and install it as a module. Can anyone help me to edit the code so that there is no need to install prettytable or other libraries.

The edit could inside function "convert".The following the my code:

```
def convert(file_dir):
    csv_file = '/Users/yingdu/Desktop/Opotokey/Europa/Data/Test_convert_csv.csv'
    txt_file = '/Users/yingdu/Desktop/Opotokey/Europa/Data/Test_convert_csv.txt'

    try:
        my_input_file = open(csv_file, "r")
        # mytable = from_csv(my_input_file)
        # my_input_file.close()
        # mytable.border = False
        # print mytable.get_string()
    except IOError as e:
        print("I/O error({0}): {1}".format(e.errno, e.strerror))

    if not my_input_file.closed:
        text_list = [];
        for line in my_input_file.readlines():
            line = line.split(",")
            text_list.append("  ".join(line))
        my_input_file.close()
        # col_width = max(len(word) for row in text_list for word in row) + 2
        # for row in text_list:
        #     print "".join(word.ljust(col_width) for word in row)

    try:
        my_output_file = open(txt_file, "w")
    except IOError as e:
        print("I/O error({0}): {1}".format(e.errno, e.strerror))

    if not my_output_file.closed:
        # my_output_file.write("#1\n")
        # my_output_file.write("double({},{})\n".format(len(text_list), 2))
        for line in text_list:
            my_output_file.write(line)
        print('File Successfully written.')
        my_output_file.close()
```

[My Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DXwRR.png)
[Expect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8kOfh.png)

By editing code to the following, column alignment can be implemented. But the length of padding could be optimized.

```
from datetime import datetime
from os.path import join
startTime = datetime.now()
import csv


def write_cols(data):
    col_spacer = " "       # added between columns
    widths = [max(len(str(item)) for item in row) for row in zip(*data)]
    return [col_spacer.join("{:<{width}}".format(col, width=widths[index]) for index, col in enumerate(row)) for row in data]

csv_file = '/Users/yingdu/Desktop/Opotokey/Europa/Data/Test_convert_csv.csv'
txt_file = '/Users/yingdu/Desktop/Opotokey/Europa/Data/Test_convert_csv.txt'

# with open(csv_file, newline='') as f_input:
with open(csv_file) as f_input:
    data = list(csv.reader(f_input))

with open(txt_file, 'w') as f_output:
    f_output.write('\n'.join(write_cols(data)))
```

Output:

```
SoftGenetics GeneMarker Trace Data Export                        
Raw Data                                                         
PAT_Ladder_1.fsa                                                 
Blue                                      Green Yellow Red Orange
50                                        51    426    45  16    
52                                        52    427    50  15    
48                                        58    415    52  17    
54                                        56    428    49  19    
59                                        60    446    47  14    
43                                        45    425    49  22
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are reading a CSV file, it would make sense to make use of Python's CSV library to read the data in.

Once you have all the rows, it would then be possible to determine the maximum width needed for each column. The following `write_cols()` function takes a list of rows, determines the maximum width needed for each column and then creates a list of rows with suitable padding for each item in a row. The list of rows is then returned.

This returned list can then be joined with newline characters and written to your output text file.

```
import csv

def write_cols(data):
    col_spacer = "  "       # added between columns
    widths = [max(len(str(item)) for item in row) for row in zip(*data)]
    return [col_spacer.join("{:<{width}}".format(col, width=widths[index]) for index, col in enumerate(row)) for row in data]

csv_file = '/Users/yingdu/Desktop/Opotokey/Europa/Data/Test_convert_csv.csv'
txt_file = '/Users/yingdu/Desktop/Opotokey/Europa/Data/Test_convert_csv.txt'

with open(csv_file, newline='') as f_input:
    data = list(csv.reader(f_input))

with open(txt_file, 'w') as f_output:    
    f_output.write('\n'.join(write_cols(data)))
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Column alignment can be implemented by your algorithm! However, it seems the padding can be optimized. I have edited my post and added the output generated by your code on it.

Comment: Could you copy/paste a sample of the CSV file using a text editor?

Answer (score 0):

I find an easier way to align the column. Just replace "," by "\t"(tab).

The following is the code:

```
from datetime import datetime
from os.path import join
startTime = datetime.now()
import csv


"""
Main Functions
"""

def main_with_just_kfilter4(file_dir, threhold_value=600):
    """
    :param file_dir:
    :return:
    """
    """1) convert file"""
    pd = convert(file_dir)
    print "File done loading"


def write_cols(data):
    col_spacer = "  " #add between columns
    widths = [max(len(str(item)) for item in row) for row in zip(*data)]
    return [col_spacer.join("{:<{width}}".format(col, width=widths[index]) for index, col in enumerate(row)) for row in data]

def convert(file_dir):
    csv_file = '/Users/yingdu/Desktop/Opotokey/Europa/Data/Test_convert_csv.csv'
    txt_file = '/Users/yingdu/Desktop/Opotokey/Europa/Data/Test_convert_csv.txt'

    try:
        my_input_file = open(csv_file, "r")
        # mytable = from_csv(my_input_file)
        # my_input_file.close()
        # mytable.border = False
        # print mytable.get_string()
    except IOError as e:
        print("I/O error({0}): {1}".format(e.errno, e.strerror))

    if not my_input_file.closed:
        text_list = [];
        for line in my_input_file.readlines():
            line = line.split(",")
            text_list.append("\t".join(line))
        my_input_file.close()
        # col_width = max(len(word) for row in text_list for word in row) + 2
        # for row in text_list:
        #     print "".join(word.ljust(col_width) for word in row)

    try:
        my_output_file = open(txt_file, "w")
    except IOError as e:
        print("I/O error({0}): {1}".format(e.errno, e.strerror))

    if not my_output_file.closed:
        for line in text_list:
            my_output_file.write(line)
        print('File Successfully written.')
        my_output_file.close()
```